# Read jboss access logs from pentaho spoon

Tags: java, jboss, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, spoon

I'm new to pentaho and learning to work with using Spoon. My task is to connect to jboss and read access logs to generate performance report . I could not find any  relevant documentation or solutions on internet . Could someone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well actually your question is wide open, because, you don't specifiy what you expect to to do with the logs, but, if you want to read csv files you can use the "Text File Input" step, and define all the required parameters (like the path where the logs reside, regex for file pattern, and based on a sample file, the columns you are gonna retrieve).

Comment: Beign said that you are interested in logs, you can use the "Text File Input" step to retrieve the data at row level, and the process it with steps like "Split field to rows" step or "Row denormaliser" step to get the values of a row separated in different columns (like first column date/time, second column message_status, etc...).

Comment: You don't specify what is your specific goal so you can only get a general answer.

Comment: @ChoCho, thanks for comments, i want to generate api performance report. I could achieve this through csv files etc, Due to several servers and approximately 30GB data to read, i want  to establish connection with server directly.

Comment: At Job level in spoon you can retrieve files via sftp, or ftp, there are multiple ways to do it, with the files in memory, you can process them at row level within transformations, still is hard to guide you.